# how to fix vb6 editor unicode?

Tags: unicode, vb6, ide, editor, ascii

I have an old vb6 project and I want to modify it, but unfortunately it's source files saved in ASCII format, when I open it with other editors (like notepadd++), there is no problem:

```
MsgBox "لطفا تاريخ  سند را انتخاب نمائيد", , "پيام"
```

but when I open the code in vb6 it shows like this:

```
MsgBox "áØÝÇ ÊÇÑíÎ  ÓäÏ ÑÇ ÇäÊÎÇÈ äãÇÆíÏ", , "íÇã"
```

how can I set some vb6 options to show them fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find my answer. Simply just navigated to Tools > Options > Editor Format > and then changed my Normal font into "Courier New (Arabic)"

Answer (score 1):

Your VB6 editor is displaying the characters in `Windows-1252` (Western Europe) encoding, but the original file is in `Windows-1256` (Arabic).  The files were possibly generated on an Arabic version of Windows and now you are on a US or European version.  With Notepad++, you may be able to re-save the file in UTF-8 or UTF-16 to allow VB6 to view it correctly.  I don't have VB6 to verify if it can read UTF-8/16 files.

A little proof (using Python 3):

```
>>> s='áØÝÇ ÊÇÑíÎ  ÓäÏ ÑÇ ÇäÊÎÇÈ äãÇÆíÏ", , "íÇã'
>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256')
'لطفا تاريخ  سند را انتخاب نمائيد", , "يام'
```

Hope this helps you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I try to save the files in (utf-8) encoding, vb6 cannot open the file, Is there any settings (maybe) in vb6 for selecting editor encoding?

Comment: I don't have VB6. Did you use the UTF8 with BOM encoding or UTF16?  The byte order mark in those encodings may give a hint to the editor as to the file format.  Another rather drastic option is to change you system's Regional and Language Options, Advanced Tab, Language for non-Unicode Programs to Arabic. After rebooting, your ANSI default will be Arabic.

Comment: Is there any way to batch converting files into utf-8 ? You know there is more than 1000 source files.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark T said Your VB6 editor is displaying the characters in `Windows-1252` (Western Europe) encoding, but the original file is in `Windows-1256` (Arabic). The files were possibly generated on an Arabic version of Windows and now you are on a US or European version.

VB6 IDE does not support UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Change your PC code page to Arabic. In Control Panel, Regional Settings, Advanced Tab, Language for non-Unicode programs, choose an Arabic locale (e.g. Saudi Arabia)

Comment: Thanks for comment, But I did that before. My region is Iran, and I set that to Persian in win7, Nothing changes!

Answer (score 0):

Change your Regional Settings in Control Panel and make the default page code Arabic.  This will fix it.